# System freeze diagnosis

Tags: freeze, system

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 Periodically, at random, the system will freeze. What /var/log file should I examine to begin diagnosis ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Next freeze I'll follow instructions at link provided and report back.

Comment: System locked up again. Apparently keyboard as well. So, cannot implement solution found at proposed link. What next? I have to cut the power to the machine to get it back. After reboot, what log should I examine ?

Comment: There are many answers. What could not you "implement"?

Comment: Your initial response directed me to a site that uses Alt+PrtScr+REISUB to solve my problem. However, that 'solution' 
 requires keyboard input. Since my keyboard does not respond when the system freezes I am unable to implement the instructions found at the site you mentioned and therefore am seeking another approach to diagnosing my 'seizure'.

Comment: I gave a link to a question with multiple answers. Read them all.

Comment: All proposals provided at the site require user input. I have absolutely no way to do that. No mouse, no keyboard, no touch-screen. Zero input possible. Arrived at the 'power-cycle' point. Running dual-boot. Windows never locks up.

Comment: There are a lot of answers with multiple reasons why freeze can happen. There is a solution for Bay Trail CPUs, Nvidia GPUs, etc. You provided zero information about your system. So nothing can be added. There are 61 answers and it doesn't look like you read more than one.

Comment: My original question did not ask WHY the machine is freezing nor how to stop it from doing so, but rather what log I should examine in order to begin a diagnosis. Not wanting to take my auto to the repair shop, but rather learn what tools I need to repair the machine myself. Ubuntu has been consistent for years in logging "events". I simply want to know which file to examine. That's it. I do not want to abuse your time by sorting through a myriad of possible solutions. Thanks for all your help. If you could suggest a file or files to examine in order to begin my diagnosis ?

Comment: There may be no log. You need to start with determining what CPU and GPU you have. It you see a solution for your case, try it. There is no magic log or file that can give an answer.

Comment: There MAY not be, but I must doubt that. My /var/log reports approximately 60 separate files. Just a suggestion as to which I might examine is all I ask. Looks like you have no suggestion. I'll dive in there and do a bit of grep-ing and see what I come up with. Thanks again.